# Linq making very inefficient Entity Framework query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

Entity Framework generates very poorly performing SQL for the following LINQ query:

```
var query = _context.Sessions
                    .Where(s => s.OrganizationId == orgId && s.Device != null && s.Device.User != null)
                    .Select(s => s.Device.User)
                    .Distinct();
```

Generates this SQL:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT
[Distinct1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Distinct1].[Email] AS [Email], 
[Distinct1].[Sex] AS [Sex], 
[Distinct1].[Age] AS [Age]
FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT 
    [Extent4].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent4].[Email] AS [Email], 
    [Extent4].[Sex] AS [Sex], 
    [Extent4].[Age] AS [Age]
    FROM   (SELECT [Extent1].[OrganizationId] AS [OrganizationId], [Extent3].[UserId] AS [UserId1]
        FROM   [dbo].[Sessions] AS [Extent1]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Devices] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[DeviceId] = [Extent2].[Id]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Devices] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent1].[DeviceId] = [Extent3].[Id]
        WHERE [Extent2].[UserId] IS NOT NULL ) AS [Filter1]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Users] AS [Extent4] ON [Filter1].[UserId1] = [Extent4].[Id]
    WHERE [Filter1].[OrganizationId] = @p__linq__0
)  AS [Distinct1]',N'@p__linq__0 int',@p__linq__0=2
```

The SQL I'm actually looking to execute is the following, which runs lightning fast:

```
select distinct u.*
from Sessions s
inner join Devices d on s.DeviceId = d.Id
inner join Users u on d.UserId = u.Id
where OrganizationId = 2
```

How can I get the Entity Framework-generated SQL to be as close to this query as possible?

Comment: It seems you need `.Select(s => s.Device.User.Email)`

Comment: Those are not equivalent queries, so it's no wonder why they would perform differently.

Comment: How does the last (edited) SQL query perform?

Comment: Can you confirm that the manual SQL query is still very fast after the edit?

Comment: My original question was poor and not asking the proper question. I corrected it.

Comment: @Yacoub, Yes, the manual query is still very fast.

Comment: why do you include ` && s.Device != null && s.Device.User != null` in your Linq query? what happens  if you remove that part?

Comment: Can you please provide the entity framework models that you are using?

Comment: I carry with me a wise advice from a experienced DBA that has been proved at least to me several times. If you have a DISTINCT in your query, something is wrong. This query can be made differently and without the DISTINCT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try starting with the users table:

```
var query = (
    from u in _context.Users
    where u.Devices.Any(d => d.Sessions
        .Any(s => s.OrganisationId == orgId)
    )
    select u
);
```

It won't do the query you specified but what it does return might have the same good performance.

Comment: I was thinking the same. In my experience this could even be better than the original sql query. +1

Comment: This drastically improved the performance of the query. Great solution.

Answer (score 4):

Why select the whole `User` entity if you just want the email?

Try this:

```
var query = _context.Sessions
                    .Where(s => s.OrganizationId == orgId && s.Device != null && s.Device.User != null)
                    .Select(s => s.Device.User.Email)
                    .Distinct();
```

Comment: I corrected my question to reflect that I'm looking for the distinct User records, not just the distinct User.Email.

Comment: What makes a user distinct? All of the fields combined? Or just some primary key value?

Comment: My original question was poor and not asking the proper question. I corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it pretty simply:

```
_context.Sessions
    .Where(s => s.OrganizationId == 2)
    .Select(s => s.Device.User)
    .Distinct();
```

You do not need to check for `null`, as it will perform an `INNER JOIN` for you.

Answer (score 0):

I dont like use the DISTINCT , if a query contains it then the query's wrong.

Other way to do it

```
var query = _context.Sessions.Include("Device.User.Email")
                    .Where(s => s.OrganizationId == orgId);
```